# Skew Matrix in Android with different origin

Tags: android, matrix, skew

I'm having some trouble trying to skew my bitmap. I want my bitmap to skew while the base of it stays fixed.

This is the matrix transformation I'm doing

```
    Matrix matrixx = new Matrix();

        matrixx.postSkew(-(events.getX() / 8) / 1000f, 0);

        matrixx.postTranslate(0, transtop);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bm2, matrixx, new Paint());
```

Where events.getX is the current position of the finger. When I do this, what happens is the top of the bitmap seems to stay fixed while the image skews to the left.

However Im trying to make it so that the bottom of the bitmap stays fixed while the image skews to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

You have to change the pivotx and pivoty in the other postSkew method.

```
boolean android.graphics.Matrix.postSkew(float kx, float ky, float px, float py)
```